# Jquery attr src does not include img tag

Tags: jquery, attr

```
var $card = $("<li>");
var imgName1 = 'images/' + rankOut + suitOut + '.png';
//assign element an image attribute
$card.attr("src", imgName1);
```

So I'm trying to add an image to my `.card` with `attr.("src"...)` however when the webpage loads, it is missing the `<img>` tag

It renders as `<li src="images/ace_of_spades.png"></li>` without the img tag.  I asked my teacher and it has to look like this

```
<ul><img src="(image location)"></ul>
```

how do i add the `<img>`?

Comment: Looks like it is homework - Would recommend you to do it yourself. Just a pointer, if `img` does not exist already, You would have to create a new `img` tag, and append it to the `li`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently setting the `src` attribute of an `li` element which of course doesn't create an `img` element. For creating an `img` element using jQuery you can code:

```
var $img = $('<img/>', {
   'src': 'images/' + rankOut + suitOut + '.png'
});
// Appending the element
$card.append($img);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
var $card = $('<li><img src="' + 'images/' + rankOut + suitOut + '.png' + '"></li>');
```